# I need to add predefined - '@domain' when user type on the form?

Tags: reactjs

My form only allows user to type their email without @domainname. for e.g. tomdickharyy@email.com the bit from @email.com is predefined. My handle change function will concatenate  "@email.com" at the end. Once the form is submitted on my state i set {email : ''} and the form is empty as expected.

The problem is when I type a new email the form will concatenate @email.com for every letter typed. I don't know how to fix this problem, any help would be great.

````
    handleChange({ target: {name, value} }){
        const domainEmail = '@email.com';

        name === "email" ? this.setState({ [name]: value + domainEmail}) : this.setState({ [name]: value});
    }  ```
````

Comment: You can use `onBlur` event on your input instead of the `change` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Remove `domainEmail` and append it again on each change. Some very rude code:

```
handleChange({ target: {name, value} }) {
  const domainEmail = '@email.com';
  name === 'email'
    ? this.setState({ [name]: value.replace(domainEmail, '') + domainEmail })
    : this.setState({ [name]: value }); 
}
```

2) Move out `domainEmail` to be purely representational, next to the input field. This is how many UI frameworks do it, see for example Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/

Then when you submit, remember to append the domain. I recommend this approach, it makes it much less fragile, removing many edge cases. It isalso very clear for the user that they should not type their email.